# Read registry value with python problems

Tags: python

I feel like I am taking crazy pills.  So for security on an api at work I am using, I have to read 2 things from the registry, that I then pass to suds.  The problem is with reading the registry values.  No matter what I do, I get "Error2 the system cannot find the file specified".  I know that the registry file is there, yet it won't let me read it. I have tried the code below on 2 different 2008 r2 servers.  On one windows 7 box, I am able to read the values...but only on one machine. Below is the code, with the actual directory I need changed(to protect anonymity)

```
from _winreg import *

key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"Software\a\b", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
devguid = QueryValueEx(key, "DeviceID")
devid = QueryValueEx(key, "DeviceGUID")
devnm = socket.gethostname()
```

If I change the directory to something other than \a\b, it works fine. I have verified that the permissions on these directories are the exact same as directories I can read from.

Also, I can run the following command from cmd and get the output I need:
    reg query HKLM\software\a\b /v DeviceGUID
But when I run it from a python script, it says cannot find file specified.

```
import os
cmd = "reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\a\b /v DeviceGUID"
a = os.system(cmd)
print a
```

Running my script as admin or anything doesn't help.  For some reason, python is unable to try and ready registry....

Comment: Your second one wouldn't work because you didn't escape the `\\`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do need to make sure that your backslashes are suitably escaped, or use raw strings as per the first code sample. I'm going to assume that you've done that.

The most likely explanation is that you use 32 bit Python on a 64 bit system. And so are subject to the registry redirector serving up the 32 bit view of the registry.

Either use 64 bit Python, or specifically open they key with a 64 bit view. Do the latter by specifying the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag.